# Motor speed controller for a 12 V motor using NPN transistor is too narrow in the input voltage

Tags: motor-controller

The current circuit:

- The voltage supplied to the resistor to get 6 V output is 7.0 V input.
- The voltage supplied to the resistor to get 12 V output is 7.3 V input.

What type of circuit would allow me to apply 0 V input to get 6 V output and 3 V input to get 12 V output?

The transistors or power transistor is a TIP120 rated at 5 A.

[image]

Comment: This circuit allows it. Are you measuring the base voltage or the microcontroller output voltage? Make sure your transistor is the right way around

Comment: This pretty much depends on the *motor power supply*. Is the output voltage referenced to ground, or "across the motor"?.

Comment: at the resistor

Comment: Where did the schematic diagram come from?

Comment: Please place the snubber diode across the motor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a circuit that will work for a linear range of voltages, but it will be very sensitive to temperature and other parameters. But PWM would be more stable, and more efficient, especially if a MOSFET is used.

[image: Linear motor control 3V-12V]

Comment: These are larger motors that need to to pull current to drive.  So putting the 100 ohm in series with the motor will reduce its speed. That characteristic curve is desired but without that resistor.

Comment: This is just an example circuit with the resistor representing a small DC motor. Components will need to be chosen based on the actual parameters required.